# Jquery mobile wont hide elements

Tags: jquery, html, mobile

Hello i have this mobile application. Which i use the jquery hide function to hide some input boxes. Well at least that is what it is supposed to do but insted i just like makes them very small, like lines if you understand my code is here you can see what i mean in the Jsfiddle i have included thanks in advance

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#facebook").hide();
  $("#twitter").hide();
  $("#google").hide();
  $("#MyName").hide();
  $("#country").hide();

$("#social").click(function(){
  if ($("#social").prop('checked') === true){
    $("#facebook").show();
    $("#twitter").show();
    $("#google").show();
    $("#MyName").show();
    $("#country").show();
  }

  else
  {
    $("#facebook").hide();
    $("#twitter").hide();
    $("#google").hide();
    $("#MyName").hide();
    $("#country").hide();
  }
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3Lcchxvv/3/

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3Lcchxvv/3/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan not to be rude or anything but i belive you misunderstood me that fiddle you made looked like my problem but my real problem is i want the lines to disapper when the form is hidden hope you understand :)

Comment: I am sorry if i was not completely clear :)

Comment: no problem :) got it set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Working fiddle**

**http://jsfiddle.net/3Lcchxvv/4/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#facebook").hide();
    $("#twitter").hide();
    $("#google").hide();
    $("#MyName").hide();
    $("#country").hide();
    $(".ui-body-inherit").hide();//added

    $("#social").click(function () {
        if ($("#social").prop('checked') === true) {
            $("#facebook").show();
            $("#twitter").show();
            $("#google").show();
            $("#MyName").show();
            $("#country").show();
            $(".ui-body-inherit").show();//added
        } else {
            $("#facebook").hide();
            $("#twitter").hide();
            $("#google").hide();
            $("#MyName").hide();
            $("#country").hide();
            $(".ui-body-inherit").hide();//added
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Awesome this works! thank you ! and thanks to everyone else that contributed! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a border around the classes added therefore its not the div that has the input is still showing its the border of the div which the input is inside it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#facebook").hide();
$("#twitter").hide();
$("#google").hide();
$("#MyName").hide();
$("#country").hide();
$(".ui-input-text, .ui-input-search").hide();

$("#social").click(function () {
    if ($("#social").prop('checked') === true) {
        $("#facebook").show();
        $("#twitter").show();
        $("#google").show();
        $("#MyName").show();
        $("#country").show();
         $(".ui-input-text, .ui-input-search").show();
    } else {
        $("#facebook").hide();
        $("#twitter").hide();
        $("#google").hide();
        $("#MyName").hide();
        $("#country").hide();
        $(".ui-input-text, .ui-input-search").hide();
    }
});

});
```

JFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lcchxvv/5/

Answer (score 0):

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lcchxvv/8/)**

Simply add a class `soc` to all your inputs (`class="soc facebook"`) and do like:

```
$(function () { // DOM READY

    var $soc = $('.soc').parent('.ui-input-text');
    $soc.hide();

    $("#social").click(function () {
        $soc.toggle( this.checked );
    });

});
```